# What's a substitute for pastis?

Tags: substitutions, alcohol

I ran across a recipe (bouillabaisse) that calls for pastis, but grocery stores in my area don't carry pastis. Is there a substitute for pastis? Thank you!

Comment: Dear all, a reminder: if you have an idea what to use, please post it as an answer, or not at all. Comments are not suited for that.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  In recipes like bouillabaisse, Pernod, Ouzo, Sambuca, or Ricard would all work as substitutes.  Basically, almost any [anise-flavored liqueur](http://www.foodsubs.com/LiqueurAnise.html) will work, although you might steer clear of high-alchohol ones like Raki.

If your local liquor selection is really poor, then maybe either skip it entirely, or add 1/4 tsp ground anise seed to the recipe and some dry white vermouth.

Comment: I've looked, but none of the four substitutes you mentioned (Pernod, Ouzo, Sambuca, or Ricard) are in stock at grocery stores in my city...

Comment: I'll add another suggestion to my answer, then.

Comment: Are you visiting grocery stores that carry liquor?  I don't know where you are, some places you need to go to an actual liquor store.

Comment: I'd steer clear of raki entirely, unless you know exactly which raki it is. Different countries use the name for completely different drinks.

Comment: True - in Sri Lanka, raki is fermented coconut water!

Comment: This doesn't help answer the question, but just in the interest of general accuracy, Ricard is a brand of pastis; it's right there on the label: [Ricard Pastis de Marseille](https://www.pernod-ricard.com/fr-fr/ricard/nos-marques/ricard/). And Pernod is arguably pastis as well - that is, if you're referring to Pernod (Classic).  Pernod now (that is, again) makes absinthe as well, which might be a good substitute for pastis, though it's much higher in alcohol.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Hi FuzzyChef, my Roasted Tomato and Saffron Vinaigrette recipe calls for: mustard, shallots, garlic, red wine vinegar, capers, thyme, orange juice, orange zest, red pepper flakes, saffron, tomatoes, olive oil, salt, pastis. In this case, do you still think ground anise seed is still a good substitute? Thank you!

Comment: if you're substituting for pastis, you're missing the anise seed flavor.  In a vinagrette, though, you should probably just use a pinch, not 1/4 tsp.  Or you could omit it, there's enough flavors in that list that I don't know that you'll miss it.

Comment: Juhasz: Absinthe, like Herbsaint, has a lot of herbal flavors in addition to the anise, which is why I didn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make [cacciucco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacciucco) instead, which is similar but from farther down the coast (Viareggio/Livorno in Tuscany). Both dishes make use of local fish though, so I would expect that to be a bigger problem than finding pastis.

Comment: One can make cioppino or whatever fish soup then. I don't see how this answers to the question.

Comment: Yes you can. My point was only that these (similar) recipes depend so much on local ingredients that you can't replicate them exactly anyway. So why not follow a similar recipe without pastis?

Comment: I see now. It mostly relies on the fresh fush available.